# Disable drawer for a specific nested screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I have a parent drawer navigator, and I want to disable the drawer in a specific screen which is few navigators down.

I've tried to put the `gestureEnabled` option on the screen, but it has other effects on a Stack Screen rather than on a Drawer Screen.

In addition I've tried using `getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute` in the drawer navigator, but it didn't give me the screen's name but one of it's parent navigators.

Comment: Can you please throw a snack demo with repro? I will help to get this solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching, I found a few ways achieving this by getting the parent navigator using the `dangerouslyGetParent`, I didn't like this approach because the navigator I needed was about three layers up.

My navigators hierarchy looks like this - Drawer => Stack => Tab => Multiple Stacks,
we keep in store the current Tab, so what I ended up doing is to dynamically set the `swipeEnabled` option on the Drawer screen based on the current tab active.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried also disabling swipe?

```js
<Drawer.Screen name="Home" 
   component={HomeScreen}
   options={{
    swipeEnabled:false,
    gestureEnabled:false
  }}
/>
```

Comment: That won't help me, because this option only applicable to Drawer navigator screens, as your example shows. I need it on a nested navigator under the Drawer.